# Magento 2 category listing page not show product

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, category-listing

In our magento store category listing page not display anyone product getting this error`"We can't find products matching the selection."` in all pages but  in admin side product  assign to category and visibility is catalog,search.If any one facing this type of issue in fronted side please reply me

Comment: Can you check if the products are enabled or not? Also check the stock availability as well.

Comment: its working right now

Answer (score 1):

If you have tried to add this product quite recentyl, i would suggest you running a reindex and then flush the cache

try running this commands in ssh from your web directory (www/http)

```
php-7.0 bin/magento indexer:reindex
rm -rf pub/static && php-7.0 bin/magento cache:clean && php-7.0 bin/magento cache:flush
```

This will re index your website, and then flush any cached pages which may be preventing products from displaying

Comment: let me try  this command

Comment: still not working

Comment: are the products enabled or disabled?

Comment: its working bro